# Length/Value for TIME type?

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I'm creating a table though it's not clear to me what length/value I'm required to input for TIME.

My TIME inputs will be fashioned as HH:MM:SS.

I've read various documentation and StackOverflow questions but a clear answer still eludes me.

Apologies in advance for such a basic question.

Comment: U can use the time datatype.

Comment: @itsme I am. My question is what the length/value for TIME should be,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)In MYSQL-

When defining a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP field, there's no need to specify the length.
Documentation -

> A DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value can include a trailing fractional
>   seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision

2)in SQL Server-

> Character length  19 positions minimum to 23 maximum

Comment: You've addressed DATETIME and TIMESTAMP. Does your answer apply to TIME?

Comment: why do you need length of time?

Comment: I'm asked to specify it when creating my table. There's a field titled "Length/Values" for each column.

Comment: Which db are you using?

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I can confirm that you answer applies to the TIME data type. I.e. No specification is required for columns intended to contain HH:MM:SS. phpMyAdmin did not prevent me from creating the table due to TIME data type being blank.